# How can I hit Django api with parameters using Postman?

Tags: django, python-3.x, testing, django-rest-framework, postman

```
@must_be_admin_user
def patch(self,request,category_id):
    '''
    Updates Data in the Category
    Parameters
    Authenticated Admin User , category_id
    '''
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=category_id)

   # IF admin is not the Creater of the Category     
    if category.created_by != request.user.id:
        Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data={"error": "You did not Create this so you cant delete this"})

    category.last_updated = timezone.now()

    updated_category = CategorySerializer(
        category, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if updated_category.is_valid():
        updated_category.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, data=updated_category.data)

    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data={"error": updated_category.errors})
```

I want to know how to send category_id using postman .
I am facing issues hitting this api using postman

Answer (score 0):

If your the URL pattern for this view is called, for instance 'patch', you could:

```
from django.urls import reverse
# Use the resulting url in Postman. This is what I use in tests.
url = reverse('patch', args=(some_id_here,), kwargs={})
```

You can use this technique for every view you have.

More [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)

Another thing you have to be aware of is that the user performing this request has to be logged in as admin, so you have set Postman cookies accordingly.

I recommend the use of a google chrome extension called "Postman Interceptor"

Good luck!